# Split up Body Content and add <hr /> between the 2 areas | WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I have a page on my WordPress site and I'd like to break up the body text after the 2nd paragraph with an `<hr />`(**without adding it in the WordPress admin side**).

Is it possible to crop my content after the 2nd `</p>`, add the `<hr />` and then continue to export the remaining text?

So the resulting HTML could be:

`<p>test1</p><p>test2</p><hr /><p>test3</p><p>test4</p>`

I'm not sure where to start with this :(

Could someone point me in the right direction?

I thought using `the_content_rss` would do the trick, but there's no real documentation on how I can achieve the above.

Many thanks for any pointers at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have received an answer for a very similar question by **str** here: [Crop string after 2nd full stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798481/crop-string-after-2nd-full-stop).

My eventual code looks like this:

```
                        <?php
                        $str = get_the_content();
                        $strArray = explode('</p>', $str);
                        $str1 = $strArray[0] . '</p> ';
                        $str2 = $strArray[1] . '</p>';
                        echo $str1;
                        echo '<hr />';
                        echo $str2;
                        ?>
```